# What color is “silver lining”?

Tags: color

I am really new to graphic design and was given a project for which I have to put silver-lining color in a circle and text. What is the meaning of silver lining?

After a suggestion I came up with the following. Do I have to ligthen this more?

[image]

Comment: I think this is the name of the Pantone color he wants you to use. See more information here: http://encycolorpedia.com/cbcdca

Comment: I think you're interpretation of "silver lining" would be just as good as anyone else's interpretation. You should ask him what he means.

Comment: Well it is hard to go by because our screen colors will vary but it seems fine. I would go with #cbcdca, rgb(203, 205, 202), CMYK (1, 0, 1, 20). This only matters in context to what the client wants. So it is best to ask and find out what he means by Silver Lining.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a *silver lining* is a pretty ethereal, subjective inspiration for a color. But, I took it to be something lighter, cloud-like almost, try #EEEEEE.

Also, take a look through [*Material Design*](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette) by Google for some color inspiration. Great documentation, excellent style guide, best bookmarked resource I ever came across.